# count substring_index

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to know how `substring_index` can only return all rows that match exactly the number of delimiters. In this case the `.`

For example this query:

```
 SELECT
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(ABC, '.', 4)
 FROM xxx
```

only should output when the row is exactly something like this (with 4 words):

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

The problem is that: this row is also showed .

```
aaa.bbb
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). `substring_index()` *is* working correctly. count is just an upper limit, if there are less than four it will return the whole string. If there are more, it will return part of the string (with up to four dots).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will return anything where ABC has 3 `.` delimiters.

```
select *
from xxx
where char_length(replace(ABC, '.', '')) + 3 = char_length(ABC)
```

You would need to multiply 3 by your delimiter length if you had a multi-character string for your delimiter.